# Show that there exists an idempotent element such that $Ra=Re$ holds for ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with 1 such that for every element $x$ in $R$, $\exists y\in R$ such that $xyx=x$ holds. Show that for any $a\in R \exists$ idempotent $e\in R$ such that $Ra=Re$

Let $a=aya$. Then I think $e=ya$ since it is idempotent but I am unable to prove $Ra=Rya$

Comment: Hint: $a \in R$...

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes! Was this just too easy?

Comment: You don't need the ring structure. The multiplicative monoid structure is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Ra=Raya\subseteq Rya\subseteq Ra$.

Therefore you have equality across the board.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly noticed, $aya = a$ implies $(ya)(ya) = ya$, i.e. that $e := ya$ is idempotent.

Now, clearly $e = ya \in Ra$ (because $y \in R$), hence $Re \subseteq Ra$. On the other hand
$$ae = aya = a \in Re$$
(because $a \in R$), therefore $Ra \subseteq Re$.

Comment: I don't get the second argument how $Ra\subset Re$, could you explain?

Comment: okay so $ra=raya=(ra)e$, hence $Ra\subset Re$

Comment: Because $a \in Re$... by definition $Rx = \{zx : z \in R\}$ so (a bit pedantically) $Ra = \{za : z \in R\} = \{z(aya) : z \in R\} = \{(za)(ya) : z \in R\} = \{(za)e : z \in R\} \subseteq \{we : w \in R\} = Re$.

Comment: @Bosnia Is my argument still unclear?

Comment: I don't understand where you use $a\in Re$. Look at my comment which proves $Ra\subset Re$ without using $a\in Re$

Comment: Your proof is implicitly using $a \in Re$ (try $r =1$). The point is that if $I$ is a left-ideal of $R$ and $a \in I$, then $Ra \subseteq I$, by the very definition of ideal (see my previous comment). It is usually easier to check that one element is in $I$ instead of checking that a whole set is in $I$...